# How to i can make Animated Contents Loading while Scroll the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animated

I am using a tutorial from this link to make the contents loading animated while scrolling.
http://www.web2feel.com/tutorial-for-animated-scroll-loading-effects-with-animate-css-and-jquery/
but when i create all it is not working good. It is not animating..
Here are my codes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Scroll effects with CSS animation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.web2feel.com/freeby/scroll-effects/assets/animate.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.web2feel.com/freeby/scroll-effects/assets/demo.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div class="topbar">
    <a href="http://www.web2feel.com/tutorial-for-animated-scroll-loading-effects-with-animate-css-and-jquery">Back to the article</a>
</div>

<div class="container">

    <header class="top">

        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="index.html"> Animated Scroll effects </a></h1>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="http://www.web2feel.com/">web2feel.com</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/">CSS Animate</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker">Viewport Checker</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <nav class="effects">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="index.html"> Demo 1 </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="index2.html"> Demo 2 </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="index3.html"> Demo 3 </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="index4.html"> Demo 4 </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="index5.html"> Demo 5 </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="index6.html"> Demo 6 </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


    <div class="post">
        <span class="icon fa fa-anchor"> </span>
        <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</h2>
        <p> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="post">
    <span class="icon fa fa-shield"> </span>
        <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</h2>
        <p> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.</p>
    </div>



    <div class="post">
        <span class="icon fa fa-globe"> </span>
        <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</h2>
        <p> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.</p>
    </div>




</div>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://www.web2feel.com/freeby/scroll-effects/assets/viewportchecker.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.post').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeIn', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
        offset: 100    
       });   
});            
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `http:` before the jQuery and Fontawesome script link. It is required if you are running the demo on local setup, instead of running it online.